# Get class property types for constructor arguments

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to somehow reference a class's property's type in the constructor because I'm finding myself writing out pretty complex types when I feel there should be a simpler way.

```js
class Foo {
  size : string
  constructor (size : typeof this.size /* doesn't work */) {
    this.size = size
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use `Foo["size"]`, but why don't you just write `constructor(public size: string) {}`? See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to the type of a property, you can use `Type["property"]`, in this case:

```
class Foo {
  size: string;

  constructor(size: Foo["size"]) {
    this.size = size
  }
}
```

But TypeScript also gives a shorthand for [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties), so you can write the whole thing as:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(public size: string) {}
}
```

You can see in this [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBjpxN) that the same JS is generated either way.